# Find maximum-width 'ramp' (leetcode)

Tags: python

The [challenge is the following](https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-width-ramp/):

> Given an array A of integers, a ***ramp*** is a tuple (i, j) for which i < j and A[i] <= A[j].  The width of such a ramp is j - i.
>
> Find the maximum width of a ramp in A.  If one doesn't exist, return 0.
>
> Input: [6,0,8,2,1,5]
>   Output: 4
>   Explanation: 
>   The maximum width ramp is achieved at (i, j) = (1, 5): A[1] = 0 and A[5] = 5

My code:

```
class Solution:
    # maximum element
    # i = minimum element

    def maxWidthRamp(self, A: List[int]):
        max_count = 0
        for i in range(0, len(A)-1):
            for j in range(1 , len(A) - i):
                if A[i] <= A[i+j]:
                    if max_count < j:
                        max_count = j

        return max_count
```

Hey, I use brute force method which works well until the output is way too large. How could I make my code more optimized or Is there other ways to solve this problem with better efficiency? If do so, Can you explain because I am a beginner.

Comment: Did you try to binary search?

Comment: I do not know how to, pls help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the result in O(NlogN) instead of O(N^2) using a list of indexes sorted in the order of the values.

With that sorted list of indexes you create two other lists.  One for the lowest preceding index and one for the largest subsequent index.

Combining these two lists will give you the maximum ramp range that includes the value at each position.

For example:

Given the list:

```
[9,8,1,0,1,9,4,0,4,1] # values
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] # original indexes
```

original indexes at sorted positions would be:

```
[3, 7, 2, 4, 9, 6, 8, 1, 0, 5] # of sorted values: [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 9, 9]
```

Because the index positions are ordered on the sorted values, any index that is after a given position correspond to a value that is >= to that indexe's value.  Conversely, indexes before a position correspond to values that are <= to that indexe's value.

So, for each position the maximum ramp range is between the smallest preceding index and the largest subsequent index.

The minimum preceding and maximum subsequent indexes will be:

```
[3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0] # minimun preceding index
[9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 5, 5, 5] # maximum subsequent index
```

This establishes ranges and we get the ramp (range size) of each sorted position by the difference between maximum and minimum:

```
[3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0] # minimun preceding
[9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 5, 5, 5] # maximum subsequent
[6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 4, 5, 5] # range sizes (difference), will select maximum
```

The largest range size is 7 for indexes 2 to 9  (values: 1 and 1)

You can implement this using a sort on (index,value) tuples and accumulate from itertools:

```
from itertools import accumulate

def maxRamp(a):
    ia = [ i for i,_ in sorted(enumerate(a),key=lambda x:x[1])]
    iMin = list(accumulate(ia,min))
    iMax = list(accumulate(ia[::-1],max))[::-1]
    i,j  = max(zip(iMin,iMax),key=lambda x:x[1]-x[0])
    return j-i
```

output:

```
a = [9,8,1,0,1,9,4,0,4,1]
print(maxRamp(a)) # 7

b = [6,0,8,2,1,5]
print(maxRamp(b)) # 4
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, But Could you clarify how to find the maximum subsequent index and minimum preceding index?

Comment: iMin and iMax are the minimum preceding indexes and maximum subsequent indexes respectively.  iMin is obtained by carrying the minimum index value forward  on the sorted index list `ia` (using accumulate).  iMax is obtained by carrying the maximum index backward (hence the double reversal with [::-1])